# Delta query : how to track group membership for users

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

According to the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/delta_query_overview) (known limitations part), tracking group membership for users is not yet supported.

An evolution was planned for March 2017. 
Will this feature be available quickly ?

Answer (score 1):

We've made some updates to the API which will remove this known limitation, allowing clients to track relationship changes across different resource classes. We will be rolling out that change shortly- it should be available in the next couple weeks.